# How to create migration dropping the table in Django 1.11?

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, migration

After I removed some functionality from Django 1.11, I want to create the migration removing the corresponding entities in the database. How can I do that?

For example, I removed the model named AB_Testing. I see the migration in

```
 ./apps/specific_app/migrations/0003_ab_testing.py
```

How to create the migration reverting it back?

Comment: Run: `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: For your first question, you already have an answer, since you see the migration for removing the model. To apply that migration, run `python manage.py migrate specific_app`. To revert it, just run the migration before the current one, which is `0002_...`. So `python manage.py migrate specific_app 0002`